# How can I let Non-Transformed Values through Scikit-Learn's Column Transformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, transformer

I'm working with a heterogenous dataset that includes numerical and categorical columns. I want to use Scikit-Learn's [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer) to [`OneHotEncode`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) the categorical data, however, `ColumnTransformer` will only recombine the columns that I apply a transformer to.

I don't want to apply a transformer to the numerical columns, how can I let the non-transformed values through the function unchanged and included in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ColumnTransformer` comes with an option called `remainder`, by default it's set to `'drop'` which means columns that aren't used by a transformer are dropped from the dataframe.

Setting this option to `remainder='passthrough'` will let the unused columns pass through the function and join the returned dataframe unchanged.

The implementation in code looks like this:

```
ColumnTransformer(transformers=YOUR_TRANSFORMER_LIST_HERE, 
                  remainder='passthrough')
```